# Estimate for the operator $(1-\Delta)^{-\sigma/2}$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have the following Banach Space

$Y_T=L^{\infty}(0,T; H^1(\Omega))\cap L^p(0,T; L_\sigma^q(\Omega))$

where $L_\sigma^q(\Omega)=(1-\Delta)^{-\sigma/2}(L^q(\Omega))$ with its norm

$$\|u\|_{Y_T}=\max_{|t|\leq T}\|u(t)\|_{H^1}+\|(1-\Delta)^{\sigma/2} u\|_{L^p(0,T; L^q)}$$ such that

$p>\max(\beta-1,2), 1/p+1/q=1/2, p<\infty$ and $\sigma=1-1/p.$

I don't get to obtain the following estimate estimate

$\|(1-\Delta)^{\sigma/2} u\|_{L^p(0,T; L^q)} \leq C\|u\|_{Y_T} $

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Is the final inequality written correctly? As presented it is trivial:
$$
\|(1-\Delta)^{\sigma/2} u\|_{L^p(0,T; L^q)} \le \|(1-\Delta)^{\sigma/2} u\|_{L^p(0,T; L^q)} + \max_{|t| \le T} \|u(t)\|_{H^1} = \|u\|_{Y_T}.$$

Comment: I'm sorry! Actually,  if I define the operator
$$
\Phi(h)(t):=e^{i\,t\,\Delta}h_0+\int_0^t e^{i(t-\tau)\,\Delta}\,\left[\mathcal{R}_0 h\,(\tau)-i\,|h(\tau)|^2h(\tau)\right]\,d\tau$$ wher $R_0$ is pseudo- differential operator of order $0$.
  I want to prove that $\Phi$ is a contraction on a ball of the Banach space $ Y_T .$ I could not get to obtain
$\|(1-\Delta)^{\sigma/2}\Phi(h)\|_{L^p(0,T; L^q)}\leq$  terms of  $\|h\|_{Y_T}.$